# JQuery Mobile jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css file?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

What is this "jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" file that is mentioned in the themeroller "To use your theme, add it to the head of your page before the jquery.mobile.structure file" and on this page:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/themes.html

"We recommend adding an external stylesheet to the head, placed after the structure and theme stylesheet references"

It isn´t mentioned anywhere else and i can´t find it. Do i need it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file contains only the base styling for JQM, it doesn't including any of the regular themes.  This will allow you to either create your own themes or override the base styling in a much easier way.